# How to apply floating label to ionic2 dropdown which has a disabled option?

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

I need to implement a ionic dropdown with disabled Select option with floating ion label. How can I do it? The disabled option value and label values should not merge. My code looks like:

```
<ion-label floating>Item Name*</ion-label>
                        <ion-select interface="popover" [(ngModel)]="obj.item_name" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" (ionChange)="onOptionChange()"
                          required>
                          <ion-option disabled selected value="">Please Select</ion-option> 
                          <ion-option value="item1">item1</ion-option>
                          <ion-option value="item2">item2</ion-option>
                        </ion-select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ion-item to contain the label and select like so

```
<ion-item>
<ion-label floating>Item Name*</ion-label>
<ion-select floating interface="popover"  [(ngModel)]="obj.item_name" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" (ionChange)="onOptionChange()" required>
  <ion-option selected value="">Please Select</ion-option> 
  <ion-option value="item1">item1</ion-option>
  <ion-option value="item2">item2</ion-option>
</ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

**Edit**

To have Please Select show up without it as an `<ion-option>`, simply include `placeholder="Please Select"` inside of your `<ion-select>` element.

Comment: Since we have given ion-option as selected its overlapping with ion-label

Comment: Can you show a snippet of  your code after editing it?

Comment: I'm fairly positive you have a css style on the select or that it's your ngModel. Take a look at this StackBlitz example I created [StackBlitzEg](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-n4m2x2?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html) I excluded your [(ngModel)] and [(ngModelOptions)] bindings and it looks just fine without any overlap.

Comment: I selected option Item1 and then I want to unselect all options using please select...I want  to display Please select value in dropdown when I dont want to select either item1 or item2...How to do that? I checked ur example, I am not able to select 'Please select' option. Please help to fix this.

Comment: In your code you pasted in your question, you put `disabled` property on your Please select option. To be able to select that option you simply have to remove the disabled property. So the please select option will look like this `<ion-option selected value="">Please Select</ion-option> `

Comment: OK....but if we use ngModel to bind the option value to a object then please select option will be considered as a value, My requirement is If I select please select option then it should be saved as a empty value in my object. How we can do this?

Comment: It would help me more if you made a stackblitz of your html including this and your typescript as well. Also, try removing `(ionChange)` from your code and see if it works.

Comment: @ChaitraR hi, try adding `placeholder="Please Select"` inside your `<ion-select>` element and removing `<ion-option selected value="">Please Select</ion-option>`

Comment: Hi Jeff, But I already have a floating label which acts like a placeholder